# Play multiple audio files from embedded resource (resx)

Tags: c#, multithreading, audio, embedded-resource

Ok so there are a couple inherent understandings

1) I know the SoundPlayer class, despite being able to load `System.IO.Stream` interfaces, is 100% **incapable** of playing more than one sound at once, despite all the multithreading and multiple-property usage.

2) I know `WMPLib` is the go to answer for playing multiple files. Sadly, it requires a URL, and according to MSDN, that URL **cannot point to a resource**.  `WindowsMediaPlayer` class is also incapable of loading `IO.Stream` interfaces.

3) I saw a hack where you write out a temporary audio file to disk and have WMPlib play that, and to that I say "polite pass"

---

Simply put, I do not want users messing with the source audio files. I intend to distribute just the executable and not a zip containing a tonn of files. This is why I opted for the `.resx`

Is there not another audio player available to C# that can take an `IO.Stream` that is capable of playing more than one thing at a time?

---

My little program is a text adventure, and I intend to have a little ambient loop playing in the background while some sound effects play to reflect what's happening on the screen.

Comment: I ended up just removing my wav files to external resources and using `WMPLib` *sigh*